# Open Sans "less than or equal" character

Tags: html, font-family

We are using Google "Open Sans" font. The "less-than-or-equal" (≤) character is supposed to be supported by this font, according to:

http://www.fontspace.com/steve-matteson/open-sans/38448/charmap

(scroll down to Mathematical Operators)

But in Chrome it shows as being rendered in Arial, despite `font-family: 'Open Sans'` style being applied. What's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

The font (Open Sans) may be not available in the computer target browser. Have import that font in your css/html?

How about this

```css
html {
  font-family: 'Open Sans'
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    Hai this is the symbol &#8804;
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes, it's being used almost exclusively, and shows rendered as Open Sans in Chrome. It's just the ≤ character that doesn't.

Comment: This is not an answer. This must be a comment.

Comment: When I run that snippet above, Chrome dev tools says that one chartacter is actually using Times New Roman:

Rendered Fonts
Open Sans—Network resource(23 glyphs)
Times New Roman—Local file(1 glyph)